# Criando uma regex para vogais em C

Tags: regex, funções

Eu preciso criar uma `regex` que verifique se uma palavra contém vogais, e depois de criar esta verificação, eu irei cortar as partes das vogais desta palavra, mas não sei como posso criar uma `regex` em C. Eu vi alguns códigos assim :

```
int reti;
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^a[[:alnum:]]", 0);
```

Poderia eu utilizar o mesmo exemplo e modificá-lo para ficar assim ? Ficando :

```
int reti;
reti = regcomp(&regex, "aeiou", 0);
```

Exemplo :

```
Input : "algoritmo"

Output : "lgrtm"
```

Como posso criar uma `regex` para fazer este trabalho ? Há alguma biblioteca em C, que eu possa importar para me ajuda no caso ?

Comment: É obrigatório o uso de regex?

Comment: Não é, mas pensei que seria melhor utilizar, teria outra forma como fazer isto ? Por exemplo, usando um if que verifique cada vogal, e depois cortar esta parte da palavra ?

Comment: Tentei fazer algumas coisas mas não obtive nenhum resultado considerável. Veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/SIyZIL).

Comment: E se mudar aquele regex[i] = '.' para alguma outra coisa, não iria funcionar ?

Comment: Sim, você pode trocar o `'.'` por qualquer outro caractere.

Comment: Eu preciso de alguma forma, fazer que o output final fique normal, e não com espaços ou caracteres a mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso comparando cada `char` do seu `array`, desta forma:

```
int testvogal(char p);
int main(void) {
    char regex[] = "algoritmo";
    int t = 0;
    char final[99];
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(regex);i++)
    {
        if (testvogal(regex[i]) == 1){
            final[t] = regex[i];
            t++;
        }
    }
    printf(final);
}

int testvogal(char p){
    char *vogal = "aeiou";
    for (int j=0;j<strlen(vogal);j++)
    {
        if (p == vogal[j])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/xqUJVi).

Comment: Essa é minha versão (em python), convertida para c, ahahaha!

Comment: @Sidon Nem vi direito como você fez, peguei o que [eu tinha feito antes](https://ideone.com/SIyZIL) como base kk

Comment: No stress! Mas que é minha versão, é. ahahaha!

Comment: Olá Francisco, obrigado pelo código, teria como eu pegar o input do usuário e testar as vogais com este código ?

Comment: Use a função `scanf`. Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/IyoUSA). Caso a resposta esteja certa, não se esqueça de marca-la como correta!

Comment: Obrigado, era deste jeito que eu queria mesmo. Marquei como resposta correta e +1.

Answer (score 1):

Como vc disse que "precisa de uma regex", pensei em apresentar somente a regex "pura", sem me preocupar com a linguagem, mas eu teria que testa-la de alguma forma, então desenvolvi em python (tenho essa regex aqui em meu "Knowledge Base" a anos, não é de minha autoria), acho que será fácil vc verter para o c.

**Regex**

```
regex = (?=[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])(.)(?!\1)(?<!\1\1)
```

**Explicando as partes:**

```
(?=[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]) Casa somente com consoantes
(.)                    A "gula" na regex, considera todas.
(?!\1) e (?<!\1\1)     Evita duplicidade no final
```

Implementação em python:

[Veja a execução do codigo no repl.it.](https://repl.it/InRO/1)

```
import re
var = 'algoritmo'
r1 = r'(?=[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])(.)(?!\1)(?<!\1\1)'
result = re.findall(r1, var)

consonants  = ''.join(str(e) for e in result)
print (consonants.split(' ')[0])
lgrtm
```

Na realidade a regex da o resultado que vc precisa mas não fazendo da forma como vc sugere, isto é, ao invés de identificar as vogais e retira-las, ela retorna somente as consoantes.

[DEMO](https://repl.it/InRO/1)

---

> **Editada Versão sem regex:** 
>  
>   Não estou com tempo e em uma maquina muito limitada, então desenvolvi uma versão em python sem o uso de regex, acho que seria facil converter para C, se quiser tente no repl que tento ajudar.

```
vogais = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

string = 'Algoritmo'

result = ''

# Percorre todas as letras da string 
for x in string:
    # convert p/ minúscula e verifica se esta em vogais 
    if x.lower() not in vogais:
        # se NÃO estiver em vogais, adiciona na string resultante 
        result += x

# Imprime o resultado    
print (result)
lgrtm
```

[Veja a execução no repl.it.](https://repl.it/In4y)

Comment: Esta parte de for e in result, seria um foreach ? Se for, tem como eu colocar de forma mais fácil em C.

Comment: Sim, na verdade o result é um objeto `list` (matriz), assim `['l', 'g','r','t','m']` a linha do `''.join(str(e) for e in result)` apenas retira cada lementeno da matriz para forma a string. Em outras linguagens pode ser totalmente diferente, como vc "resolve" uma regex em c? Pode até ser q o resultado ja venha pronto.

Comment: Pelo que sei regex em C é muito mais complexo, não basta criar uma lista do que você vai verificar e pronto, e nem tem biblioteca pra mexer com isto. Tem que importar elas por outro lugar, por isso é mais difícil do que em Python.

Comment: Editei a resposta e coloquei uma versão sem o uso de regex, agora vai. :-)

Comment: Qual versão do c vc esta usando?

Comment: Consegui uma forma de fazer isso, estou escrevendo minha resposta.

Comment: Dei +1 por que você deu umas ideias interessantes também, obrigado.